# Do Wscript.Shell shortcuts support file extensions longer than 3 characters

Tags: powershell, vbscript, shortcut

I am trying to use Wscript.Shell to create a desktop shortcut in a Powershell script.  The target path is a HTML file on a network drive.  I specified the full path, but when the shortcut was created, the file extension was truncated to .htm.  Since the file ends in .html, this obviously doesn't work.

Is there any way to avoid truncating the file name?  My guess is that Wscript.Shell doesn't support target file extensions longer than 3 characters.  Is this correct?

**Here is my code (Powershell):**

```
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$shortcut = $wshell.CreateShortcut("C:\users\parts.AGRISERVICELLC\Desktop\AgriWeb.lnk")
$shortcut.TargetPath = "S:\Service\agriweb_dairy\home.html"
$shortcut.WorkingDirectory = "S:\Service\agriweb_dairy"
$shortcut.IconLocation = "C:\arch2.ico"
$shortcut.Save()
```

This code creates the shortcut, complete with my icon.  But the target path is truncated to `S:\Service\agriweb_dairy\home.htm`.

Update:  Interestingly enough, this problem does not occur if I run the commands above in a local Powershell session.  However, if I remote into another computer using Enter-PSSession, the extension truncates to 3 characters.  The issue isn't the length of the path - if I shorten the path and change the extension to ".htmll", it still shortens the extension to ".htm".
Also, the extension does not truncate if the path is on the C: drive.  But when I use a network drive, the extension truncates.

Comment: That doesn't happen here. The .html extension is still in the link. The link is also functional.

Comment: I experimented a little more, and it does work fine as long as I am running the commands in a local Powershell session.  When I remote into another computer with Enter-PSSession, the extension truncates to 3 characters again.

Comment: I can confirm the problem: `powershell "$shortcut=(New-Object -COM WScript.Shell).CreateShortcut('%userprofile%\Desktop\test.lnk');$shortcut.TargetPath='Z:\test.docx';$shortcut.Save(); Write-Host $shortcut.TargetPath"` truncates the extension to `Z:\test.doc`. But `powershell "$shortcut=(New-Object -COM WScript.Shell).CreateShortcut('%userprofile%\Desktop\test.lnk');$shortcut.TargetPath='C:\test.docx';$shortcut.Save(); Write-Host $shortcut.TargetPath"` works fine: `C:\test.docx`. The only difference in the two command lines before are the volume letter `c:` vs. `z:`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is related to https://web.archive.org/web/20060709170134/https://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=263324
If the target drive letter does not exist on the machine where the shortcut is created, Windows assumes the drive can only handle filenames in the 8.3 format